# Local Storage (Woocommerce Registration)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, local-storage

woocommerce registration will take email validation.
and after registration we will directly go to same page but it loading.
so i wanna make notification after registration in woocommerce.
any suggest?

```
<div class="alert success">
            <span class="closebtn">&times;</span>
            <strong>Registration Success!</strong> Check Email.
    </div>
    <form method="post" class="register-new-account">
        <div class="">
            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_start' ); ?>

            <?php if ( 'no' === get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_username' ) ) : ?>

                <p class="woocommerce-FormRow woocommerce-FormRow--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                    <label for="reg_username"><?php _e( 'Username', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <!-- <span class="required">*</span> --></label>
                    <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="username" id="reg_username" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['username'] ) ) echo esc_attr( $_POST['username'] ); ?>" />
                </p>

            <?php endif; ?>

            <p class="woocommerce-FormRow woocommerce-FormRow--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                <label for="reg_email"><?php _e( 'Email address', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <!-- <span class="required">*</span> --></label>
                <input type="email" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="email" id="reg_email" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['email'] ) ) echo esc_attr( $_POST['email'] ); ?>" />
            </p>

            <?php if ( 'no' === get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_password' ) ) : ?>

                <p class="woocommerce-FormRow woocommerce-FormRow--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                    <label for="reg_password"><?php _e( 'Password', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <!-- <span class="required">*</span> --></label>
                    <input type="password" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="password" id="reg_password" />
                </p>

            <?php endif; ?>

            <!-- Spam Trap -->
            <!-- <div style="<?php echo ( ( is_rtl() ) ? 'right' : 'left' ); ?>: -999em; position: absolute;"><label for="trap"><?php _e( 'Anti-spam', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label><input type="text" name="email_2" id="trap" tabindex="-1" autocomplete="off" /></div> -->

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form' ); ?>
            <?php do_action( 'register_form' ); ?>

        </div>

            <p class="woocomerce-FormRow form-row margin-top-30">
                <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-register', 'woocommerce-register-nonce' ); ?>
                <!-- <input type="submit" class="woocommerce-Button button" name="register" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Register', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" /> -->
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default size-new-account" name="register" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Create new account', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
            </p>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_end' ); ?>

    </form>
```

just testing my button

```
localStorage.setItem('register1','success');

jQuery('input.btn.btn-default.size-new-account').click(function() {
  var reg = localStorage.getItem('register1');
  jQuery('.alert.success').show();
 });
```

how can i show the notification after registration? thanks for help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [show div after process register, woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45346579/show-div-after-process-register-woocommerce)

Comment: Adding same question multiple times ?

Comment: Add a hidden post value.. 

   <input type="hidden" name="reigstration_show">

   <?php if (isset($_POST['registration_shoow'])) {
        echo '<div></div>';
    } ?>