# Show div after process register, woo-commerce

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

After registration process in website, I want to show a hidden div
the div are in the same page.
but after registration, the page will load and show the same page.

here's the form-handler.php

```
public static function process_registration() {
    $nonce_value = isset( $_POST['_wpnonce'] ) ? $_POST['_wpnonce'] : '';
    $nonce_value = isset( $_POST['woocommerce-register-nonce'] ) ? $_POST['woocommerce-register-nonce'] : $nonce_value;

    if ( ! empty( $_POST['register'] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $nonce_value, 'woocommerce-register' ) ) {
        $username = 'no' === get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_username' ) ? $_POST['username'] : '';
        $password = 'no' === get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_password' ) ? $_POST['password'] : '';
        $email    = $_POST['email'];

        try {
            $validation_error = new WP_Error();
            $validation_error = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_process_registration_errors', $validation_error, $username, $password, $email );

            if ( $validation_error->get_error_code() ) {
                throw new Exception( $validation_error->get_error_message() );
            }

            // Anti-spam trap
            if ( ! empty( $_POST['email_2'] ) ) {
                throw new Exception( __( 'Anti-spam field was filled in.', 'woocommerce' ) );
            }

            $new_customer = wc_create_new_customer( sanitize_email( $email ), wc_clean( $username ), $password );

            if ( is_wp_error( $new_customer ) ) {
                throw new Exception( $new_customer->get_error_message() );
            }

            if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_registration_auth_new_customer', true, $new_customer ) ) {
                wc_set_customer_auth_cookie( $new_customer );
            }

            wp_safe_redirect( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_registration_redirect', wp_get_referer() ? wp_get_referer() : wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ) );
            exit;

        } catch ( Exception $e ) {
            wc_add_notice( '<strong>' . __( 'Error', 'woocommerce' ) . ':</strong> ' . $e->getMessage(), 'error' );
        }
    }
}
```

and the div

```
<div class="alert success">
    <span class="closebtn">&times;</span>
    <strong>Registration Success!</strong> Check Email.
</div>
```

and this's the js code

```
   jQuery('input.btn.btn-default.size-new-account').click(function() {
  jQuery('.alert.success').show();
});
```

but the problem, how can I understand the flow of registration and I can use condition or another way. so the notify will show if the validation is success and also show after load page.

Comment: you can add id as well if you want

Comment: I don't have much experience on php and I really cannot make out much of the posted code. So I would like to ask directly. Does the above script on allow you to register and get redirected to another page or the same page gets reloaded?

Comment: actually on register process its ok,
the problem just, when i click button even i leave everything blank the notification still show, coz i just set the function onclick. even the process is failed to register, the success notification will show

Comment: You can try to use `template_redirect` wordpress hook.

Answer (score 0):

After processing your registration (php code), execute following line

```
wc_add_notice('Registration successful') ;
```

Then you don't need new div

Comment: i still confuse with it.

Comment: 1. inside your process registration function perform an action which will save a value to cookie.... say just_registered = 1

Comment: now after your registration your page will load again right ?

Comment: now inside init action try to get that cookie value, if value is there that means user just have registered.

Comment: so i declare register = 1 on process registration
and for the js file, i will read the cookies and reset it?

Comment: when i console.log the $register on register process, i can't get the value of register

Comment: im so sory, i just courious how to learn this code. cos i like to learn about programmer from all of you

Comment: for registration process, you are using a php function, inside that function user set_cookie function to save the value first... see this link 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: then from java script you can get cookie value 
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: @Reza I have modified the answer now. Check it.